# Finding a unit speed parametrisation for $\alpha(t)= 0.5 (t, 1/t, \sqrt{2} \log(t))$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

I'm trying to find a unit speed parametrisation for the curve $\alpha: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t
$$\alpha(t)= 0.5 (t, 1/t, \sqrt{2} \log(t)).$$

However, 
$$s(t) = 0.5 (t - \frac{ 1}{ t} ),$$
and as $t \to 0$, $s \to \infty $, so I don't know how to interpret this result, or how to find $t(s)$.

I also tried reparametrization of the given curve with $x \to e^x$, but that gave me 
$$s = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^x)*(3 + e^{-4x})^{0.5}dx,$$
but this integral also does not converge.

**Question:**

How to find a unit speed parametrisation for such a curve ?

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $t$:

$$t-\frac1t=2s$$ or $$t^2-2st-1=0,$$ which gives $$t=s\pm\sqrt{s^2+1}.$$

Comment: But, zero is not in the domain of $\alpha$, so you cannot take $t_0 = 0$ in the integral.

Comment: so $t - \frac{ 1}{t } \not = s $ in that sense.

Comment: Plus, if we even try to make that the limit of the lower bound of the integral goes to zero $0$, the integral for $s$ diverges.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: what integral ? Are you trying to find the total curve length ?? You've been asking for a unit speed parameterization, I am giving you one.

Comment: Then, the question is how did you find it ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: are you kidding ? That's what my answer says.

Comment: I'm talking about how did you get $t - \frac{1}{t } = 2s $ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: you wrote it yourself. How did you get it ?

Comment: Well, I was trying to find the arch length, and started parametrisation from $t_0 = 1$, but that parametrisation does not give the arc length; though that is not the question we are trying to answer in here

Comment: @onurcanbektas: the question is about unit speed parameterization.